# typescript - return specific class instance from mixed array using typed function

Tags: arrays, function, typescript, mixed, typed

Is it possible to retrieve specific type from mixed array using typed function?

```
public plugins: (Tool|Service)[] = [];
getTools(): Tool[]{
    return this.plugins.filter(t => t instanceof Tool);
}
```

So far I have no luck. Typescript is throwing following message[image]

> TS2322: Type '(Tool | Service)[]' is not assignable to type 'Tool[]'. Property 'onclick' is missing in type 'Service'.

Is there any way how I can set function type to `Tool[]` here?

Here is full code:

```
interface Required {
    id: string
    title: string
    owner: string
    type: 'user' | 'admin'
}

class P {
    id; title; owner; type;
    constructor(config: Required){
        this.id = config.id || 'uniqid';
        this.title = config.title || 'Title';
        this.owner = config.owner || 'user';
        this.type = config.type;
    }
}

interface ToolRequired extends Required{
    onclick: () => void
}

class Tool extends P {
    onclick;
    constructor(config = {} as ToolRequired){
        super(config);
        this.type = 'tool';
        this.onclick = config.onclick
    }
}

class Service extends P {
    constructor(config = {} as Required){
        super(config);
        this.type = 'service'
    }
}

class Storag {
    static types = {
        tool: Tool,
        service: Service,
        undefined: Tool,
    };
    public plugins: (Tool|Service)[] = [];
    setPlugin(config = {} as Required){
        const Type = Storag.types[config.type];
        this.plugins.push( new Type(config) );
    }
    getTools(): Tool[]{
        return this.plugins.filter(t => t instanceof Tool);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tack on an `as Tool[]` at the end.

```
public plugins: (Tool|Service)[] = [];
getTools(): Tool[]{
    return this.plugins.filter(t => t instanceof Tool) as Tool[]; // << here
}
```

The reason you need to do this is because the Typescript compiler isn't smart enough to know that when you do such a filter it will *only* return `Tool`s. A `.filter` on any array will *usually* return the same type as the previous array, which is what the compiler *assumes* here - a `Tool|Service` array.

The compiler is smart enough to know, however, that a `Tool|Service` can be reduced down to only `Tool`s - as such, you can do an `as Tool[]` at the end to tell the compiler `I know what I'm doing - the type that ".filter" returns will only be Tools here`, and the compiler will listen and respect it as such.

You can read more about the `as` keyword here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html (scroll down or search for "Type assertions").

Comment: hasn't typescript 2.4 just allowed this - return types as inference targets (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/06/27/announcing-typescript-2-4/)

Comment: `Array.map` definitely works - `Array.filter` doesn't :c (i.e. `plugins.map(a => a as Tool)` vs `plugins.filter(a => a instanceof Tool) as Tool[]`)